# MySQL cluster dump with logfile

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

Here's a problem I'm having in MySQL cluster and hoping one of you has an answer since it seems like something pretty obvious.

I'm producing dumpfiles of our MySQL cluster databases which of course include the CREATE LOGFILE GROUP / CREATE TABLESPACE commands in them. There doesn't seem to be any way though to do either of these two things:

1) Ideally, to create dumpfiles which include some version of ... "DROP LOGFILE GROUP IF EXISTS" for logfiles/tablespace so I can import them in existent databases and overwrite the data without producing 'ERROR 1528 (HY000) at line 22: Failed to create LOGFILE GROUP' errors.

As it stands all I can do is have a script which removes the logfile creation from the dumpfile before importing it, which isn't great, because my database already has those.

2) Otherwise, if there's a separate syntax which produces a dumpfile *without* the logfile/tablespace creation, that would also work.

It just seems that the DROP  IF EXISTS syntax should be present for logfiles/tablespace but it doesn't seem to be, unless I'm missing something.

I'd greatly appreciate any help on this.

Regards,
John.